# getLastAuthenticationError return boolean

Tags: symfony, authentication, symfony5

When i submit the loginForm, Utils return me a boolean 1. I read the docs many times and it's the first time i meet this problem. I don't know what means the error 1. When i want to make this line "{{ Error.messageKey|trans(Error.messageData, 'security') }}" for get the msg error, i have this message "Impossible to access an attribute ("messageKey") on a boolean variable ("1")."
Thank you.

** Security.yaml **

```
security:
    encoders:
        App\Entity\User:
            algorithm: bcrypt

    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers
    providers:
        # used to reload user from session & other features (e.g. switch_user)
        app_user_provider:  
                entity: 
                    class: App\Entity\User
                    property: email
    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            anonymous: true
            lazy: true
            provider: app_user_provider 
            


            form_login: 
                login_path: account_login
                check_path: account_login

            logout:
                path: account_logout
                target: account_login
            guard:
                authenticators:
                    - App\Security\AccountTypeAuthenticator

            # activate different ways to authenticate
            # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#firewalls-authentication

            # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/impersonating_user.html
            # switch_user: true

    # Easy way to control access for large sections of your site
    # Note: Only the *first* access control that matches will be used
    access_control:
         # - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
        # - { path: ^/profile, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

```
*** AccountController ***

/**
     * @Route("/login", name="account_login")
     */
    public function login(AuthenticationUtils $utils): Response
    {
        $error = $utils->getLastAuthenticationError();
        $username = $utils->getLastUsername();
        // var_dump($error);
        return $this->render('account/login.html.twig', [
            'Error' => $error !== null,
            'username' => $username
        ]);
    }
```

```
*** AccountTypeAthenticator ***

<?php

namespace App\Security;

use App\Entity\User;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Generator\UrlGeneratorInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\UserPasswordEncoderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\CustomUserMessageAuthenticationException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\InvalidCsrfTokenException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Security;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserProviderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Csrf\CsrfToken;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Csrf\CsrfTokenManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Guard\Authenticator\AbstractFormLoginAuthenticator;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Guard\PasswordAuthenticatedInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Util\TargetPathTrait;

class AccountTypeAuthenticator extends AbstractFormLoginAuthenticator implements PasswordAuthenticatedInterface
{
    use TargetPathTrait;

    public const LOGIN_ROUTE = 'account_login';

    private $entityManager;
    private $urlGenerator;
    private $csrfTokenManager;
    private $passwordEncoder;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager, UrlGeneratorInterface $urlGenerator, CsrfTokenManagerInterface $csrfTokenManager, UserPasswordEncoderInterface $passwordEncoder)
    {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
        $this->urlGenerator = $urlGenerator;
        $this->csrfTokenManager = $csrfTokenManager;
        $this->passwordEncoder = $passwordEncoder;
    }

    public function supports(Request $request)
    {
        return self::LOGIN_ROUTE === $request->attributes->get('_route')
            && $request->isMethod('POST');
    }

    public function getCredentials(Request $request)
    {
        $credentials = [
            'email' => $request->request->get('email'),
            'password' => $request->request->get('password'),
            'csrf_token' => $request->request->get('_csrf_token'),
        ];
        $request->getSession()->set(
            Security::LAST_USERNAME,
            $credentials['email']
        );

        return $credentials;
    }

    public function getUser($credentials, UserProviderInterface $userProvider)
    {
        $token = new CsrfToken('authenticate', $credentials['csrf_token']);
        if (!$this->csrfTokenManager->isTokenValid($token)) {
            throw new InvalidCsrfTokenException();
        }

        $user = $this->entityManager->getRepository(User::class)->findOneBy(['email' => $credentials['email']]);

        if (!$user) {
            // fail authentication with a custom error
            throw new CustomUserMessageAuthenticationException('Email could not be found.');
        }

        return $user;
    }

    public function checkCredentials($credentials, UserInterface $user)
    {
        return $this->passwordEncoder->isPasswordValid($user, $credentials['password']);
    }

    /**
     * Used to upgrade (rehash) the user's password automatically over time.
     */
    public function getPassword($credentials): ?string
    {
        return $credentials['password'];
    }

    public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token, string $providerKey)
    {
        if ($targetPath = $this->getTargetPath($request->getSession(), $providerKey)) {
            return new RedirectResponse($targetPath);
        }
        return $this->redirectToRoute('Homepage');
        // For example : return new RedirectResponse($this->urlGenerator->generate('some_route'));
        throw new \Exception('TODO: provide a valid redirect inside '.__FILE__);
    }

    protected function getLoginUrl()
    {
        return $this->urlGenerator->generate(self::LOGIN_ROUTE);
    }
}
```

```
*** login.html.twig ***

{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block title %}
    Connexion !
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="bg-light py-3 px-3">
            <h1>Connexion !</h1>

            {{ Error }}

            {# {% if Error %}
    <div>{{ Error.messageKey|trans(Error.messageData, 'security') }}</div>
{% endif %}  #}
            {% if app.user %}
        <div class="mb-3">
            You are logged in as {{ user.username }}, <a href="{{ path('account_logout') }}">Logout</a>
        </div>
    {% endif %}
            {% if Error %}
                <div class="alert alert-danger">L'email ou le mot de passe est incorrect</div>

                
            {% endif %}
                    
            
                <form action="{{ path('account_login') }}" method="post">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="email">Email</label>
                        <input type="text" name="_username" id="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Adresse email" required value="{{ username }}">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="password">Mot de passe</label>
                        <input type="password" name="_password" id="" class="form-control" placeholder="Mot de passe" required>

                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Connexion !
                        </button>
                    </form>
            </div>
            
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    {% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1):

You send to your view the result of a comparison

```
'Error' => $error !== null
```

I think you want to do this

```
'Error' => $error
```